# Programmatically create survey monkey embed

Tags: .net, surveymonkey

Using the .net wrapper for survey monkey I'm fetching a list of survey's for an account. I'm then allowing the user to select one of these survey to be embedded on my site. Is it possible to generate the embed code dynamically based on the id or anything returned via the API much like you would embed a YouTube video based on its id?

The surveymonkey site is currently erroring out when trying to create the embed code so I can't use that as a starting point. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SurveyMonkey API allows you to create email (create_flow, send_flow) and weblink (create_collector) collectors. There is currently no method for creating website collectors other than through SurveyMonkey's user interface.

If there's an existing website collector, you can select it from the list returned but get_collector_list. Alternatively, you can link to the survey in an external tab/page using a weblink collector.